# Matplotlib spacing in xaxis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have a pandas dataframe,

```
SPL         COUNT

ASDSFGDFG   2889
BDFGDFGSD   1942
CSDFGSDFG   1660
DDSFGDSFG   837
ESDFGDSFF   742
FDFGSDFDF   577
GDFGDSFGF   523
HDFGDSFGF   480
```

when i try to plot, the xais is not showing the SPL names properly,

[image: X-Axis]

the code which i have written right now:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
plt.tight_layout()
ax.plot(doc_spl['spl'], doc_spl['total_count'])
```

**how to add spacing to show the xaxis properly, can i make the text vertical ? and give space between the ticks?**

Comment: Did you check any of the Matplotlib documentation or it's Gallery of examples for orienting the x Axis labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?, try adding the below lines of code to your code:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.gca().margins(x=0)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
tl = plt.gca().get_xticklabels()
maxsize = max([t.get_window_extent().width for t in tl])
m = 0.2 # inch margin
s = maxsize/plt.gcf().dpi*150+2*m
margin = m/plt.gcf().get_size_inches()[0]

plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=margin, right=1.-margin)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(s, plt.gcf().get_size_inches()[1])
```